# Fisher information of parametric channel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, information, metrology

Suppose $\Phi_\theta$ is a quantum channel whose action can be written for any state $\rho\in \mathcal S(\mathcal H_S)$ in the Stinespring representation as  $\Phi_\theta(\rho)= \text{Tr}_E(U_\theta (\rho_S\otimes \tau_E) U_\theta^\dagger)$ for some unitary $U_\theta$ living on the total space $S\otimes E$. Suppose also that, if $a = (a_1, b_1,...,a_n, b_n)^t$ is the vector of the combined modes describing the system $S$ (so that the initial state of the system $\rho_S$ can be written as some function $\rho_S=f(a, a^\dagger)$), such unitary is described by its action on them $U_\theta a^\dagger U_\theta^\dagger=u_\theta a^\dagger$ for some matrix $u_\theta$.

The quantum Fisher information of a state $\rho_\theta$ is generally defined as $H(\theta) = \text{Tr}(\partial_\theta \rho_\theta L_\theta)$, where $L_\theta$ is the SLD operator. More explicitly, there exists the following formula
$$H(\theta) = 2\int_0^{+\infty} dt \ e^{-\rho_\theta t}\partial_\theta \rho_\theta e^{-\rho_\theta t}$$
which only involves $\rho_\theta$ and its derivatives. Assuming knowledge of $u_\theta$, is there a simple way to express the QFI for a channel such as $\Phi_\theta$, in terms of *any* initial state $\rho$?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a definition for $\rho_{\theta}$?

Comment: @flippiefanus $\rho_\theta=\Phi_\theta(\rho)$ I presume

Comment: To rephrase: this is a bosonic system subject to a (linear optics) unitary transformation and loss; is there a simple expression for QFI in that case?

Comment: Some possible simplifications: we know $U_\theta=\exp(i \mathbf{r}_\theta\cdot \mathbf{G})$ for the vector of generators $\mathbf{G}$ of SU($2n$). If $\mathbf{r}_\theta=\theta\mathbf{n}$ for fixed $\mathbf{n}$, as is often the case, the QFI will be $\leq$ Var${}_{\rho_\theta}(\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{G})$. Alternatively, if $\rho_S$ and $\tau_E$ are pure, then we know QFI equals the max QFI over purifications of $\rho_\theta$, one of which is the pure state $U_\theta(\rho\otimes \tau)U_\theta^\dagger$, so the QFI $\leq$ (and maybe saturates) Var${}_{\rho\otimes \tau} (-i dU/d\theta U^\dagger)$

Comment: @flippiefanus Yes, $\rho_\theta = \Phi_\theta(\rho)$.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic We can assume $\rho_S$ to be pure and just take $\tau_E$ as the empty ket. I'm by any means not an expert in quantum metrology; can you tell me where that inequality is coming from? Also, I don't suppose it can be restated as something that only involves the matrix $u_\theta$?

Comment: @Quantastic it will always depend on the initial state $\rho$: imagine starting with the vacuum, then $(\rho\otimes \tau)$ is an eigenstate of $U_\theta$  (because $U$ conserves excitation number for the two modes due to the $u_\theta$ that you've given), then $\partial_\theta \rho_\theta=0$, while other states have nonzero derivatives for the same $U$. As for the inequalities, those are just other properties of QFI from other formulations, of which there are a whole bunch

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I don't mind the dependency on $\rho$. I meant that I'm looking for some explicit expression, if it exists, involving operations on $u_\theta$ and $\rho$ as matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have access to the auxiliary mode $\tau_E$ and want to find the quantum Fisher information of that scenario. The true QFI will be upper bounded by that, because the information in $\rho_\theta$ is strictly less than the information in the joint system.

Since $U_\theta(\rho_S\otimes\tau_E)U_\theta^\dagger\equiv |\Psi_\theta\rangle\langle\Psi_\theta|$ is pure by construction ($\rho_S=|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ and $\tau_E=|0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $|\Psi_\theta\rangle\equiv U_\theta|\psi\rangle\otimes |0\rangle\equiv U_\theta |\Psi_0\rangle$), its QFI is found to be
$$H(\theta)=4(\langle \partial_\theta\Psi_\theta|\partial_\theta\Psi_\theta\rangle-|\langle \Psi_\theta|\partial_\theta\Psi_\theta\rangle|^2)=4(\langle\Psi_\theta|G^2|\Psi_\theta\rangle-\langle\Psi_\theta|G|\Psi_\theta\rangle^2)=4(\langle\psi|\otimes\langle 0|G^2|\psi\rangle\otimes|0\rangle-\langle\psi|\otimes\langle 0|G|\psi\rangle\otimes|0\rangle^2),$$ where the last equality used unitary invariance of the variance of the generator $G\equiv -i (\partial U_\theta/\partial \theta) U_\theta^\dagger$. In this case, $U_\theta$ is an SU($2n$) operation represented by a $2n\times 2n$ matrix $u_\theta$ and so $G$ will be a linear combination of the generators of SU($2n$). The coefficients of the linear combination may depend on $\theta$, depending on the form of $u_\theta$. One set of generators contains all of the generators of the form (cf [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Generalized_Gell-Mann_matrices_(Hermitian))) $c_i c_j^\dagger +c_i^\dagger c_j$ ($i\neq j$), $\mathrm{i}(c_i c_j^\dagger -c_i^\dagger c_j)$ ($i\neq j$),  and $c_1^\dagger c_1 -c_j^\dagger c_j$ ($j>1$) for $\mathbf{c}=(a_1,b_1,\cdots, a_n,b_n)$. Since $G$ is a linear combination of those, its variance is given by the sum of all of the covariances of those generators. The generators with odd $i$ and $j$ deal with variances with respect to the original state $|\psi\rangle$ and depend on both $|\psi\rangle$ and the form of $U_\theta=\exp(i G)$. (The form of $u_\theta$ told us that $G$ was made from generators of SU($2n$).) The generators with even $i$ and/or $j$ all have their expectation values vanish, because all of the $b$ modes start in their vacuum states, except for the final $n-1$ generators that retain the term $c_1^\dagger c_1=a_1^\dagger a_1$ that can have nonzero expectation value. As for their second-order moments, many of them vanish but not all, because for example $\langle (c_i c_2^\dagger +c_i^\dagger c_2)(c_j c_2^\dagger +c_j^\dagger c_2)\rangle=\langle (c_i^\dagger c_2)(c_j c_2^\dagger)\rangle=\langle c_i^\dagger c_j\rangle$ when mode 2 begins in the vacuum state.

All that work, just for an upper bound to the QFI. It turns out that the QFI is actually equivalent to the [minimum QFI over all purifications] (https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys1958), so we can say (I think, maybe there is more to the optimization)
$$H_\theta=\min_{|\phi\rangle}4(\langle\psi|\otimes\langle \phi|G^2|\psi\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle-\langle\psi|\otimes\langle \phi|G|\psi\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle^2),$$ where now we enjoy none of the simplifications from above because $|\phi\rangle$ is not necessarily the vacuum state for the $b$ modes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume that everything still works out when $\Phi$ couples multiple environments $E_1,...E_m$ to the system to account for photon losses in different spaces, as long as $U_\theta$ is taken as an element of $\text{SU}(mn)$. 
At any rate, is there no way to express the products $\langle \Psi_0|G|\Psi_0\rangle$ and $\langle\Psi_0|G^2|\Psi_0\rangle$ in terms of $u_\theta$ and $|\Psi_0\rangle$?

Comment: Writing $\text{Tr}[G\rho]=-i\text{Tr}[U_\theta^\dagger\rho \dot U_\theta]$ and $\rho$ in terms of its characteristic function, we should be able to make some progress if we know a rule for $U_\theta^\dagger a^\dagger \dot U_\theta$; I don't think however that there is a way to rewrite this in a simple way...

Comment: @Quantastic it would be SU($m+n$) in that case (although never a need for $m>n$). The way to express the products is as a sum of covariances (taken with respect to $|\Psi_0\rangle$ of the operators like $c_i^\dagger c_j +c_j^\dagger c_i$ as I expressed above, weighted by coefficients found by expressing $u_\theta$ in terms of generators of the Lie algebra

Comment: @Quantastic so it will all simplify into variances and covariances of terms at most quadratic in creation and annihilation operators. That can be written in terms of characteristic functions, sure

Comment: @Quantastic maybe you want this: $U_\theta=\exp(i \mathbf{r}_\theta\cdot \mathbf{G})$ for a vector of c-numbers $\mathbf{r}_\theta$ and a vector of generators $\mathbf{G}=(a_1^\dagger a_2+a_2^\dagger a_1,-i(a_1^\dagger a_2-a_2^\dagger a_1),\cdots)$. Because of group theory, $u_\theta$ corresponds to the same group element in the $2n\times 2n$ irreducible representation, so $u_\theta=\exp(i \mathbf{r}_\theta\cdot \mathbf{g})$ for the *same* coefficients $\mathbf{r}_\theta$. Now we need the matrix exponential, and $\mathbf{g}$ is made from the vector of matrix representations of the generators

Comment: @Quantastic for example, $\mathbf{g}=(\begin{pmatrix}0&1&\mathbf{0}\\1&0&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}^\top&\mathbf{0}^\top& \mathbf{0}^\top\mathbf{0}\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&-i&\mathbf{0}\\i&0&\mathbf{0}\\\mathbf{0}^\top&\mathbf{0}^\top& \mathbf{0}^\top\mathbf{0}\end{pmatrix},\cdots)$

Comment: So, let me see if I understand this correctly (sorry, groups are not my forte). The vector $\mathbf g$ is given by the generalized Gell-Mann matrices representing the generators, and if $u_\theta$ is known, then from their relationship it should be possible to find $\mathbf r_\theta$ and therefore those products involving $G$. I'm missing one thing: can you clarify why its variance is given by the sum of all of the covariances of the generators?

Comment: Another thing: perhaps this requires a different question, but can the problem be simplified if $u_\theta$ is a block matrix? In particular, for $m=2$, if all $3\times 3$ diagonal blocks $(u_\theta)_{ii}$ are defined by the same rule, and likewise for the off-diagonal blocks $(u_\theta)_{ij}$. I can more easily find the coefficients for these smaller matrices, but given that I should then take the matrix exponential I'm not sure what the connection is with the full problem.

Comment: @Quantastic $Var(a X+ bY)=a^2 Var(x)+ b^2 Var(y)+ab [Cov(X,Y)+Cov(Y,X)]$, so if $G$ is a linear combination then the variance of $G$ is a linear combination of covariances. As for block diagonals, the matrix logarithm or matrix exponential of a block diagonal will respect that structure

Comment: Right! So, just to make sure I've got everything down: we have $G=\partial_\theta \mathbf r_\theta\cdot \mathbf G$, so once we get $\mathbf r_\theta$ from $u_\theta=e^{-i\mathbf r_\theta\cdot \mathbf g}$ we just need to compute $$\text{Var}_\rho(G)=\sum_{ij}\partial_\theta r_\theta^{(i)}\partial_\theta r_\theta^{(j)}\text{cov}(G_i, G_j)_\rho. $$ One last thing: the generators in $\mathbf G$ retain the form they have in your answer even when, for instance, $\mathbf c=(a_1,b_1,c_1,...,a_n,b_n,c_n$)?

Comment: @Quantastic almost. Unfortunately your definition for $G$ is not true, it is only defined in terms of $U$ but you can't just take out that term from the exponential because the derivative may not commute with the unitary. [Wilcox](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1705306) says for $U=\exp(A)$ that $\partial U/\partial \lambda=\int_0^1 \exp[(1-\beta)A]\frac{\partial A}{\partial \lambda}\exp(\beta A)d\beta$, reminiscent of your Lyapunov form of the QFI, so it is often easier to take the matrix logarithm or to compute the QFI numerically

Comment: @Quantastic no, you must use the generators of SU($2n$)! The whole point of group theory is that the elements of the group behave the same no matter the representation, such that the things you do in the matrix version are correct for the operator version. While it is true that there is more than one set of generators, [wiki for the Lie algebra that generates the special unitary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Lie_algebra) says "The Lie algebra 
$\mathfrak {su}(n)$ of SU(n) consists of n × n skew-Hermitian matrices with trace zero"

Comment: Right. That makes it significantly more complicated, to the point where I don't think this is a viable strategy unless $U_\theta$ is a very simple transformation. Allow me one last question: I don't understand why you write that $U_\theta\in \text{SU}(2n)$ even in the case where the vector of modes is $\mathbf c=(a_1,b_1,c_1,...,a_n,b_n,c_n)$, since the representation $u_\theta$ needs to have dimension $3n\times 3n$ in order to act on $\mathbf c$. Perhaps I misunderstood your point.

Comment: @Quantastic sorry yes you can say $3n$. The generators will take the form $G_k=\mathbf{c}^\dagger g_k \mathbf{c}$ for the operator version, while the matrix version is $g_k$